# pygame Collision Detection for a Cannonball

Tags: compiler-errors, collision-detection, pygame

For the past week I have been working on a Cannon Game for class. Our current iteration is to add a target and collision detection. From my understanding pygame.draw functions return Rect objects. I append these objects to a list and pass this list to my cannonball. Cannonball then uses that list to detect if it has hit anything. However I receive "if self.current_ball.Rect.collidelist(self.collision_objects) > -1:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Rect'" error.

```
    def draw(self, screen):  
        '''
        Draws the cannonball
        '''      
        self.current_ball = pygame.draw.circle(screen, color["red"],(round(self._x),round(self._y)), 5)
        return self.current_ball

    def move(self):
        '''
        Initiates the cannonball to move along its
        firing arc
        '''
        while self.active:
            prev_y_v = self.y_v
            self.y_v = self.y_v - (9.8 * self.time_passed_seconds)
            self._y = (self._y - (self.time_passed_seconds * ((prev_y_v + self.y_v)/2)))
            self._y = max(self._y, 0)
            self._x += (self.delta_x)
            #self.active = (self._y > 0)
            self.collision_detect()
            if self.collide == True:
                self.active = False

    def collision_detect(self):
        '''
        Detects if the current cannonball has collided with any object within the 
        collision_objects list. 
        '''
        if self.current_ball.Rect.collidelist(self.collision_objects) > -1:
            self.collide = True
```

I'm not quite sure if there is anything wrong with this code, or is it actually the issue with the collision_objects list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rect objects doesn't have Rect attributes. Try removing the .Rect attribute as follows:

```
def collision_detect(self):
    '''
    Detects if the current cannonball has collided with any object within the 
    collision_objects list. 
    '''
    if self.current_ball.collidelist(self.collision_objects) > -1:
        self.collide = True
```

There may be more than one problem here. As far as I could see self.current_ball should be a Rect object and there is nothing in the code you posted that suggests it receives "None".

If the correction above doesn't work, you may need to check the rest of the class code to check if you are calling the your self.draw() function properly.

Comment: I had tried removing the Rect after realizing "why am I trying to call Rect if its a Rect object?" Unfortunatly it still gives me the same error. Within the GUI I store the drawn object as cannonball_object, and the same with the target after they are drawn. I attempted to use just the two objects rather than a list(thinking ahead) and used colliderect. Honestly I am perpelexed by this.

Comment: I found the reason for the error. I had my objects being stored after the collision_detection was attempting to run. Set the order straight and the program ran without issue.